# Instance variable not changing

Tags: python, class

The instance variable 'x' is not changing as expected after assignment.

This is my code:

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self, x=0):
    self.x = x
    if self.x>=100:
        self.x = int(str(self.x)[-2:])
    elif self.x<0:
        self.x = -1

p = Foo()
print(p.x)
p.x = 125
print(p.x)
p.x = -945
print(p.x)
```

Expected:

```
0
25
-1
```

However I got this:

```
0
125
-945
```

Comment: The `__init__` method is called when you instantiate `Foo`. It is not called every time you update the `x` attributes.

Comment: If you need a special setter that modifies the attribute assignment, use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get your desired results this way:

```
p = Foo()
print(p.x)
p = Foo(125)
print(p.x)
p = Foo(-945)
print(p.x)
```

`__init__` is only called when instatiating the class; e.g. `Foo(125)`.

---

if you want this code to be called any time you modify `self.x`, you should use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        if self._x >= 100:
            # self._x = int(str(self._x)[-2:])
            self._x %= 100
        elif self._x < 0:
            self._x = -1
```

this way

```
p = Foo()
print(p.x)
p.x = 125
print(p.x)
p.x = -945
print(p.x)
```

works as you expect it.

also note the improved way on how to eliminate the leading digits: `self._x %= 100`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method is called when you instantiate Foo, as stated by @khelwood already, you could add a method like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x

    def numVal(self, x=0):
        if self.x>=100:
            self.x = int(str(self.x)[-2:])
        elif self.x<0:
            self.x = -1
        return self.x

p = Foo()
print(p.x)
p.x = 125
print(p.numVal(p.x))
p.x = -945
print(p.numVal(p.x))
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
25
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
            if self.x>=100:
                self.x = int(str(self.x)[-2:])
            elif self.x<0:
                self.x = -1

x=0
p = Foo(x)
print(p.x)

x=125
p = Foo(x)
print(p.x)

x=-945
p = Foo(x)
print(p.x)
```

Comment: Perhaps add some context to this code so that others who find this can understand whats going on. StackOverflows guidelines say "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer